# Running Umbraco on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-sql-database

Is this a supported scenario in Windows Azure 2013.

1. Website hosted as an Azure Webites (not virtual machine)
2. SQL Azure (not SQLCE)

I'm concerned that #1 will have issues with folder permissions and the durability of files such the umbraco.config and other related caching files.

Do anyone have first hand experience if this is a fully supported scenario or Virtual Machines is the way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

2) Running Umbraco in Azure in Websites or VM, you will need to change the data layer to have a retry framework. Otherwise you will get errors like the following :

[Deploying Umbraco to SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753696/deploying-umbraco-to-sql-azure/16492261#16492261)

This is an known issue in Azure with Umbraco but you can fix it.

Comment: Is this still a problem in 2013 and Umbraco v6?

Comment: I have not looked at V6 of Umbraco source code but I believe it will still be, I cannot see the transient fault handling framework coming into the Umbraco build anytime soon because of dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are these files changes when umbraco runs. If they are not changing, then you need to worry.
If they are changing, then you might to either settings files to some permanent store (e.g. blob) or use azure VM

Comment: Yes, they can change.  For example uploading new images to the CMS actually copies the file to the web root and when publishing happens the caching files in the web root gets refreshed.  So perhaps VMs are the better option...